# Unique ranking of atoms in a molecule

Tags: rdkit, cheminformatics

I was trying to rank the atoms of two PDB files of a same compound but different plymorphs collected from CCDC,  using RdKit canonical ranking. But It generates different ranking for the two PDB of same compound. Do you have any suggestions how to rank the atoms or any other packages to fix the issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: +1 but is your question answered [here](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/issues/2006)?

Comment: I am not sure it solves my question. Surprisingly the ranking of few polymorphs matches but not for all.